# Add new environment variables to Lambda using Cloud Formation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have a nested Cloud Formation Template (multiple templates within a root template )to create a complete web application.
Lambda is created in the first template and few environment variables are added to it.
The later part of the templates also produces some values that has to be added as environment variables.
Is there a way to attach these environment variables to the existing lambda function?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so, but there are a few options. If you could change the stack dependency order, you could build the stack creating the values depended upon first. If you cannot, you can store your environment variables in SSM Parameter Store as mentioned [in this knowledge center article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-common-environment-variables/).

So you set the environment variable to a path where the value can be expected, then when creating the stack that knows the value, you store it at that path. When the lambda runs, you just do get parameter.